# How to get click handler on animated canvas dot on MapBox map?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, maps, mouseevent, mapbox

I am looking at [this demo](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-animated/) from MapBox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Add an animated icon to the map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.thekey.12345';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
    });
    var size = 200;
    // This implements `StyleImageInterface`
    // to draw a pulsing dot icon on the map.
    var pulsingDot = {
      width: size,
      height: size,
      data: new Uint8Array(size * size * 4),
      // When the layer is added to the map,
      // get the rendering context for the map canvas.
      onAdd: function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      },
      // Call once before every frame where the icon will be used.
      render: function() {
        var duration = 1000;
        var t = (performance.now() % duration) / duration;
        var radius = (size / 2) * 0.3;
        var outerRadius = (size / 2) * 0.7 * t + radius;
        var context = this.context;
        // Draw the outer circle.
        context.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(
          this.width / 2,
          this.height / 2,
          outerRadius,
          0,
          Math.PI * 2
        );
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 200, 200,' + (1 - t) + ')';
        context.fill();
        // Draw the inner circle.
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(
          this.width / 2,
          this.height / 2,
          radius,
          0,
          Math.PI * 2
        );
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 1)';
        context.strokeStyle = 'white';
        context.lineWidth = 2 + 4 * (1 - t);
        context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        // Update this image's data with data from the canvas.
        this.data = context.getImageData(
          0,
          0,
          this.width,
          this.height
        ).data;
        // Continuously repaint the map, resulting
        // in the smooth animation of the dot.
        map.triggerRepaint();
        // Return `true` to let the map know that the image was updated.
        return true;
      }
    };
    map.on('load', function() {
      map.addImage('pulsing-dot', pulsingDot, {
        pixelRatio: 2
      });
      map.addSource('dot-point', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
          'type': 'FeatureCollection',
          'features': [{
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
              'type': 'Point',
              'coordinates': [0, 0] // icon position [lng, lat]
            }
          }]
        }
      });
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'layer-with-pulsing-dot',
        'type': 'symbol',
        'source': 'dot-point',
        'layout': {
          'icon-image': 'pulsing-dot'
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How do make it so I can handle on click on the dot, and make the cursor a pointer when you hover over it?

Comment: There are only two ways to detect mouse events on any figures at canvas. `context.isPointInPath(path,x,y)` - where the circle should be a Path2D or `context.isPointInPath(x,y)` - where the circle is current path in context. `x,y` is position of mouse event at `canvas`. So you should first listen for `mouseover` event on whole canvas, then at any `mousemove` event compare the event point with path.

Comment: The second method to find out the intersection is drawing a colorful circle on non-visible canvas with same width and height, in same position. Then `getImageData(x,y,1,1)` in same point with mouse event at basic canvas. Then you take the color of the point and test if it is the target color of the circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are actually not as hard as it might seem. As others have suggested you could do it with some trickery - but it is not needed as the required functionality is built into Mapbox itself yet!
If you look up the [API reference](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map-events) for it's own `map` object, you'll notice there are a couple of interesting events:

**click**, **mouseenter**, and **mouseleave**

Usually those are bound to the actual map and added like:

```
map.on('click', function() {
console.log('clicked');
});
```

Now what's that good for you might ask yourself. If we look back at the sample code you've provided, we can see that the animated dot is added to the map on it's own layer called `layer-with-pulsing-dot`.
One thing the API reference doesn't really mention is, that there is an additional second parameter to the `.on()` method which let's you specify an ID to a specific layer.

So all we have to do is adding some listeners to the `layer-with-pulsing-dot` layer.

The click event is obvious of course and the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are used to transform the mouse cursor to a pointer and back.

Try adding this block of code after  `map.addLayer({ ... });`

```
  map.on('click', 'layer-with-pulsing-dot', function(e) {
    alert('Someone clicked long:' + e.lngLat.lng + ' lat:' + e.lngLat.lat)
  });

  map.on('mouseenter', 'layer-with-pulsing-dot', function() {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
  });

  map.on('mouseleave', 'layer-with-pulsing-dot', function() {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the co-ordinates of the dot in your canvas.
On mouse move event, check if the mouses co-ordinates are in the dot's co-ordinates.